# Is it a lower bound a.e?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ a positive nonvanishing function such that $\frac{1}{f(t)} \ge y-x$  almost everywhere for $y≥x$  with $x$, $y$ and $t$ in $[0,2]$.

Is it a true that $\frac{1}{f(t)} \ge2$  almost everywhere in $[0,2]$?

Comment: Yes, I guess. In particular, you want $\frac1{f(t)}\ge 2-0$ for all $t$

Comment: What is the definition domain of $f$?

Answer (score 1):

No.
From given condition we found $y\in[0,2]$ and $y\ge x$. denote $\frac 1{f(t)}=y-x$, $x=0.1$, $y=1$ then $\frac 1{f(t)}=0.9\le2$. and if you draw $z=y-x$, $y=2$, $y=0$ graphics in 3d coordinate, you could easily find the area that meet $z\ge y-x$, $y\le2$, $y\ge0$. this is exactly the range of $\frac 1{f(t)}$, which doesn't meet $\frac 1{f(t)}\ge2$

Comment: I know that, (1/f(t))>0 a.e. But how to prove that there exists a positive constant m, such that (1/f(t))≥m a.e. in[0,2]?